# read keyvault secret from Synapse notebook

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-keyvault, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I am trying to read keyvault secret from Synapse notebook using:

```
s = TokenLibrary.getSecret(kv, secret_name)
```

It works when I am running it in debug mode, but fails when it is scheduled. I granted Synapse server managed identity Get and List secret policy. What is different when it is scheduled?

Comment: Are you running synapse notebook using pipeline? 'but fails when it is scheduled' can you give information like how you scheduled this?

Comment: So, notebook is referenced by a Synapse pipeline
And Synapse pipeline is scheduled by Synapse Trigger

Comment: Can you share the documentation that you're following? Or any error messages that you're getting?

Comment: I've found this library here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python

I got this error: Access token couldn't be obtained

Comment: Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)\n<ipython-input-1-6affc5f3> in <module>\n      1 kv = 'dakeyvaultdev'\n----> 2 tpldm_scrt = TokenLibrary.getSecret(kv, \"cm-account\")\n      3 print(tpldm_scrt)\n\n~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)\n   1302 \n   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)\n-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(\n   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

Comment: same error occurs when I put linked service as a 3rd parameter in function call: TokenLibrary.getSecret(kv, "cm-account", "ls_local_kv")

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
TokenLibrary.getSecret(linkedService, secret)
```

or:

```
TokenLibrary.getSecretWithLS(linkedService, secret)
```